# Select random row from a PostgreSQL table with weighted row probabilities

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics, probability

Example input:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
 id | percent   
----+----------
  1 | 50 
  2 | 35   
  3 | 15   
(3 rows)
```

**How would you write such query, that on average 50% of time i could get the row with id=1, 35% of time row with id=2, and 15% of time row with id=3?**

I tried something like `SELECT id FROM test ORDER BY p * random() DESC LIMIT 1`, but it gives wrong results. After 10,000 runs I get a distribution like: `{1=6293, 2=3302, 3=405}`, but I expected the distribution to be nearly: `{1=5000, 2=3500, 3=1500}`.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by wrong results?

Comment: @Clodoaldo, after 10k runs of above query i get next results ( position to count ): {1=6293, 2=3302, 3=405}, but i expect them to be nearly like that: {1=5000, 2=3500, 3=1500}.

Comment: @OlegGolovanov OK, so the query works, but the distribution is wrong.

Comment: Very interesting problem. Thanks for the question. In future it's worth being more specific about things like *why* something "doesn't work" or has "wrong" results, but otherwise ... good brain food, thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT random() * (SELECT SUM(percent) FROM YOUR_TABLE) R
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id, SUM(percent) OVER (ORDER BY id) S, R
    FROM YOUR_TABLE CROSS JOIN CTE
) Q
WHERE S >= R
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1;
```

The sub-query `Q` gives the following result:

```
1  50
2  85
3  100
```

We then simply generate a random number in range [0, 100) and pick the first row that is at or beyond that number (the `WHERE` clause). We use common table expression (`WITH`) to ensure the random number is calculated only once.

*BTW, the `SELECT SUM(percent) FROM YOUR_TABLE` allows you to have any weights in `percent` - they don't strictly need to be percentages (i.e. add-up to 100).*

[[SQL Fiddle]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/525f9/21)

Comment: ... but it doesn't; it produces a *different* wrong distribution. See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b67b6/2

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes, the problem was probably in repeated generation of the random number. By moving it to common table expression, it is generated only once, giving a [much nicer result](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d2a88/1).

Comment: That's a nicer, faster query than what I wrote; we took the same approach to solving the problem but your solution is a heck of a lot more efficient than using nested windows to calcluate a weighted range like I did.

Comment: This probably doesn't need to be stated, but the CTE could be avoided if you know beforehand what the sum of your probabilities will be. For instance, if all rows' percent columns always add up to 100%, then we can take out the CTE, remove the cross join, and replace `where S >= R` with `where S >= random() * 100

Comment: @JohnFawcett Unfortunately, that wouldn't work, since `random()` would get evaluated (and produce a different value) for each row. But we want it to produce one value, and then pick a row based on that one value. Please see the history of the answer - I got it wrong the first time exactly because of multiple generation of random values until Craig Ringer spotted the problem.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic ah - then following what I was initially saying (removing the CTE), could we make the inner query column list be:
` id, sum(percent) over(order by id) S, random() R

Comment: @JohnFawcett I don't believe so, because of the same problem. We need to search through ALL rows (and return one row) based on SAME random value. Your proposal would cause a search on different random values.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic you're absolutely right. I don't know why I didn't try it `select id, random() from some_random_table` returns a different `random()` value for each row. CTE it is. Thanks!

Comment: Why order by id: It would seem you don't need any ordering, but if you did want to order it, you should order it by percent, as if somehow the percents are not in order the results will be skewed.

Comment: @SamGoody Because the same order was used in the windows function SUM. It doesn't really matter what order is used, as long as **no** two elements are in the same "position", and both the window function and the "cut-off" (at the end of the query) use the same order. In principle, any key could have been used, but not `percent` since it's not a key and two rows may share the same percent, skewing the result to whatever row the DBMS prefers to return first.

Comment: @Branko I meant S, not percent, my bad. S must be unique and is guaranteed to be in the right order (and logically, it makes sense to sort on S). EDIT: Unless the percentage is zero, in which case 2 users could match (the latter having 0%) and if we sorted by S a user with a 0% chance could win. Whereas if you sort by ID both times, that cannot happen, since a 0 would always match the user before him.

Comment: @SamGoody `S` is a running total. It follows whatever order was specified in `SUM ... ORDER BY ...`.

Comment: Just to overcomplicate this; is there a reasonable way to do this for a table representing several weighted probabiilities related to another table. eg, rather than just `id` and `percent` columns, we also have, say `user_id`, and we want to get a random weighted item from this table for each of 2 or 3 users.

Comment: @dougalg Looks like an extra JOIN to me.

Comment: This really seems to work.  I've looked at many of these, and this is the best so far!

Answer (score 11):

> ORDER BY random() ^ (1.0 / p)

from the algorithm described by Efraimidis and Spirakis.

Answer (score 5):

Branko's accepted solution is great (thanks!). However, I'd like to contribute an alternative that is just as performant (according to my tests), and perhaps easier to visualize.

Let's recap. The original question can perhaps be generalized as follows:

> Given an map of ids and **relative weights**, create a query that returns a random id in the map, but with a probability proportional to its relative weight.

Note the emphasis on relative weights, not percent. As Branko points out in his answer, using relative weights will work for anything, including percents.

Now, consider some test data, which we'll put in a temporary table:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE test AS
SELECT * FROM (VALUES
    (1, 25),
    (2, 10),
    (3, 10),
    (4, 05)
) AS test(id, weight);
```

Note that I'm using a *more complicated* example than that in the original question, in that it *does not* conveniently add up to 100, and in that the *same weight* (20) is used *more than once* (for ids 2 and 3), which is important to consider, as you'll see later.

The first thing we have to do is turn the weights into probabilities from 0 to 1, which is nothing more than a simple normalization (weight / sum(weights)):

```sql
WITH p AS ( -- probability
    SELECT *,
        weight::NUMERIC / sum(weight) OVER () AS probability
    FROM test
),
cp AS ( -- cumulative probability
    SELECT *,
        sum(p.probability) OVER (
            ORDER BY probability DESC
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS cumprobability
    FROM p
)
SELECT
    cp.id,
    cp.weight,
    cp.probability,
    cp.cumprobability - cp.probability AS startprobability,
    cp.cumprobability AS endprobability
FROM cp
;
```

This will result in the following output:

```
 id | weight | probability | startprobability | endprobability
----+--------+-------------+------------------+----------------
  1 |     25 |         0.5 |              0.0 |            0.5
  2 |     10 |         0.2 |              0.5 |            0.7
  3 |     10 |         0.2 |              0.7 |            0.9
  4 |      5 |         0.1 |              0.9 |            1.0
```

The query above is admittedly doing more work than strictly necessary for our needs, but I find it **helpful to visualize the relative probabilities this way**, and it does make the final step of choosing the id trivial:

```sql
SELECT id FROM (queryabove)
WHERE random() BETWEEN startprobability AND endprobability;
```

Now, let's put it all together with a test that **ensures** the query is returning data with the expected distribution. We'll use `generate_series()` to generate a random number a **million times**:

```sql
WITH p AS ( -- probability
    SELECT *,
        weight::NUMERIC / sum(weight) OVER () AS probability
    FROM test
),
cp AS ( -- cumulative probability
    SELECT *,
        sum(p.probability) OVER (
            ORDER BY probability DESC
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) AS cumprobability
    FROM p
),
fp AS ( -- final probability
    SELECT
        cp.id,
        cp.weight,
        cp.probability,
        cp.cumprobability - cp.probability AS startprobability,
        cp.cumprobability AS endprobability
    FROM cp
)
SELECT *
FROM fp
CROSS JOIN (SELECT random() FROM generate_series(1, 1000000)) AS random(val)
WHERE random.val BETWEEN fp.startprobability AND fp.endprobability
;
```

This will result in output similar to the following:

```
 id | count  
----+--------
 1  | 499679 
 3  | 200652 
 2  | 199334 
 4  | 100335
```

Which, as you can see, tracks the expected distribution perfectly.

### Performance

The query above is quite performant. Even in my average machine, with PostgreSQL running in a WSL1 instance (the horror!), execution is relatively fast:

```
     count | time (ms)
-----------+----------
     1,000 |         7
    10,000 |        25
   100,000 |       210
 1,000,000 |      1950
```

### Adaptation to generate test data

I often use a variation of the query above when generating test data for unit/integration tests. The idea is to generate random data that approximates a probability distribution that tracks reality.

In that situation I find it useful to compute the start and end distributions **once** and storing the results in a table:

```sql
CREATE TEMP TABLE test AS
WITH test(id, weight) AS (VALUES
    (1, 25),
    (2, 10),
    (3, 10),
    (4, 05)
),
p AS ( -- probability
    SELECT *, (weight::NUMERIC / sum(weight) OVER ()) AS probability
    FROM test
),
cp AS ( -- cumulative probability
    SELECT *,
        sum(p.probability) OVER (
            ORDER BY probability DESC
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ) cumprobability
    FROM p
)
SELECT
    cp.id,
    cp.weight,
    cp.probability,
    cp.cumprobability - cp.probability AS startprobability,
    cp.cumprobability AS endprobability
FROM cp
;
```

I can then use these precomputed probabilities repeatedly, which results in extra performance and simpler use.

I can even wrap it all in a function that I can call any time I want to get a random id:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getrandomid(p_random FLOAT8 = random())
RETURNS INT AS
$$
    SELECT id
    FROM test
    WHERE p_random BETWEEN startprobability AND endprobability
    ;
$$
LANGUAGE SQL STABLE STRICT
```

### Window function frames

It's worth noting that the technique above is using a window function with a non-standard frame `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. This is necessary to deal with the fact that some weights might be repeated, which is why I chose test data with repeated weights in the first place!

Comment: Hey, How could this be extended to pick N distinct entries (in this case from the test table)?
Also, if possible I'd like to insert the picks immediately into another table.

Answer (score 2):

Your proposed query appears to work; see [this SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3039b/3). It creates the wrong distribution though; see below.

To prevent PostgreSQL from optimising the subquery I've wrapped it in a `VOLATILE` SQL function. PostgreSQL has no way to know that you intend the subquery to run once for every row of the outer query, so if you don't force it to volatile it'll just execute it once. Another possibility - though one that the query planner might optimize out in future - is to make it appear to be a correlated subquery, like this hack that uses an always-true where clause, like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3039b/9

At a guess (before you updated to explain *why* it didn't work) your testing methodology was at fault, or you're using this as a subquery in an outer query where PostgreSQL is noticing it isn't a correlated subquery and executing it just once, like in [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3039b/4). .

**UPDATE:** The distribution produced isn't what you're expecting. The issue here is that you're skewing the distribution by taking *multiple samples* of `random()`; you need a *single* sample.

This query produces the correct distribution ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/2dbeb/2)):

```
WITH random_weight(rw) AS (SELECT random() * (SELECT sum(percent) FROM test))
 SELECT id
FROM (                   
  SELECT 
    id,
    sum(percent) OVER (ORDER BY id),
    coalesce(sum(prev_percent) OVER (ORDER BY id),0) FROM (
      SELECT 
        id,
        percent,
        lag(percent) OVER () AS prev_percent
      FROM test
    ) x
) weighted_ids(id, weight_upper, weight_lower)
CROSS JOIN random_weight
WHERE rw BETWEEN weight_lower AND weight_upper;
```

Performance is, needless to say, horrible. It's using two nested sets of windows. What I'm doing is:

- Creating (id, percent, previous_percent) then using that to create two running sums of weights that are used as range brackets; then
- Taking a random value, scaling it to the range of weights, and then picking a value that has weights within the target bracket

Comment: looks to me like you proved that it's not working.  3 is coming in at 4% whereas it should be 15%.

Comment: @digitaljoel Good point. I was presuming that their helpful "not working" was an issue with uncorrelated subquery optimisation producing the same result across a set, not an unexpected distribution. Hmm. *tries to dig up old probability lectures in brain*.

Comment: @digitaljoel Got it; the trouble was multi-sampling of the random number.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something for you to play with:

```
select t1.id as id1
  , case when t2.id is null then 0 else t2.id end as id2
  , t1.percent as percent1
  , case when t2.percent is null then 0 else t2.percent end as percent2 
from "Test1" t1 
  left outer join "Test1" t2 on t1.id = t2.id + 1
where random() * 100 between t1.percent and 
  case when t2.percent is null then 0 else t2.percent end;
```

Essentially perform a left outer join so that you have two columns to apply a between clause.

Note that it will only work if you get your table ordered in the right way.

Comment: You know it occurred to me that if you include a "sacrificial" row (0,0) in your table then you could simply do an inner join instead, and remove the pesky case statements. It would simplify the query a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Branko Dimitrijevic's answer, I wrote this query, which may or may not be faster by using the sum total of `percent` using tiered windowing functions (not unlike a `ROLLUP`).

```
WITH random AS (SELECT random() AS random)
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id, percent,
    SUM(percent) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rank,
    SUM(percent) OVER () * random AS roll
    FROM test CROSS JOIN random
) t WHERE roll <= rank LIMIT 1
```

If the ordering isn't important, `SUM(percent) OVER (ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS rank,` may be preferable because it avoids having to sort the data first.

I also tried Mechanic Wei's answer ([as described in this paper, apparently](http://utopia.duth.gr/~pefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf)), which seems very promising in terms of performance, but after some testing, [the distribution appear to be off](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/e8eb2/1/0) :

```
SELECT id
FROM test
ORDER BY random() ^ (1.0/percent)
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [this paper](http://utopia.duth.gr/%7Epefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf) note that we have to compute `random() ^ (-1.0 / p)` (***minus*** one).

```sql
ORDER BY RANDOM() ^ ( -1.0 / p )
```

The [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/a7d444/1) example will give you:

```
id  percent  freq
1   40       0.39795 
2   30       0.29540 
3   20       0.20635
4   10       0.10030
```

### Full Code

---

#### Schema

```sql
CREATE TABLE test
    (id integer, percent integer)
;
    
INSERT INTO test
    (id, percent)
VALUES
    (1, 40),
    (2, 30),
    (3, 20),
    (4, 10)
;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_random_row() RETURNS integer AS $SQL$
    SELECT id
    FROM test
    ORDER BY RANDOM() ^ ( -1.0 / percent )
    LIMIT 1
$SQL$ LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE;
```

#### Query

```sql
SELECT id, count(id)/10000.0 AS freq
FROM (
  SELECT get_random_row()
  FROM generate_series(1,10000)
) x(id)
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very old question but I found this very simple approach, so might still be helpful for someone

```
SELECT id
FROM test
WHERE percent > 0
ORDER BY -log(random()) / percent
```

`log(random())` creates a logarithmic distribution of values 0 - 1. The `-log(random())` ensures that smaller values of random() (closer to 0) produce larger output values.
Dividing by `percent` biases the distribution based on the weight. Rows with a higher `percent` get lower (more negative) values on average, thus appearing earlier when sorted.

The distribution of results for this query is pretty accurate http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/3cac7/1

```
id  freq
3   0.147
2   0.3559
1   0.4971
```