# Select random row with different probability - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, probability

I want select random row with different probability column based:

```
ID     Type
Bike   1
Moto   1
Asus   2
Car    1
Apple  2
John   3
```

If i do this i will have random probability:

> select top 1 * from Items order by newid()

I want John (type 3) has 70% probability to get, and 5% for type 1 and 25% for type 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select random row from a PostgreSQL table with weighted row probabilities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13040246/select-random-row-from-a-postgresql-table-with-weighted-row-probabilities)

Answer (score 4):

I would use the [`RAND()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177610.aspx) function instead of `NEWID()`.

Using `RAND()`, we can generate a random number between 1 and 100, and then use a `CASE` statement to select a `type` based on the number randomly generated.

According to MSDN:

> `RAND()` returns a pseudo-random float value from 0 through 1,
>   exclusive

Meaning that multiplying `RAND()` by 100 will give us a number from 0 to 99.  Adding 1 changes the range to 1 to 100.

If after selecting which `type` to return, you want to randomly select a record from that `type`, you can then add a `SELECT TOP 1`... `ORDER BY NEWID()` to get a random record of that type:

```
DECLARE @Random INT
SET @Random = (RAND() * 100) + 1

SELECT TOP 1 ID, Type
FROM Items
WHERE Type = CASE
  WHEN @Random > 30 THEN 3
  WHEN @Random BETWEEN 6 AND 30 THEN 2
  ELSE 1
END
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

[See it here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/128d2/23)... run it a few times to see that the results match the probabilities.

Comment: What's the point of the + 1? It seems like it throws off the percentages making it 4% for 1, 25% for 2 and 71% for 3.

Comment: @Love2Learn I updated the answer with an explanation for the `+1`.  Without it the range would be 0 to 99 based on the possible return values for `RAND()`

Comment: Yeah, just noticed you were implicitly converting to an int, right on. I think you need to adjust the ranges because there are only 4 chances for a 1, 25 for a 2 and 71 for a 3. Change 3 to 31+ and 2 to 6 through 30?

Comment: @Love2Learn You're right... thanks for pointing that out! Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

You mean 5% probability for entire type=1 group, or you want every record of type=1 to have 5% probability of being selected?
If it's second option, then you have 70+15+50=135 = no way you can do this.
If it's first option, then you'll have to make 2 draws - first for a type, and then for a row in this type.