# Rails query random records using weights

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

let say I have a model `Product`

There are products

```
id | title   | weight (integer)
1  | Sugar   | 1
2  | Salt    | 1
3  | Pepper  | 2
4  | Coke    | 5
```

So, I want to get few (lets say 2) random products using weights.

```
Product.limit(2).rand_with_weights # =>
# The probability of coke is in array is 5x times bigger than salt or sugar and 2.5x times bigger than pepper
# The probability of pepper is in array is 2x times bigger than salt or sugar
# The probability of salt or sugar in array is equal
```

How can I make this query?

Comment: Do you want to query with random wieghts?

Comment: I want to query random records using their weights

Comment: Try this `Product.order("RANDOM()*weight").limit(2)`

Comment: This might be really helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13040717/312907 although what @Pavan says seems quite reasonable, be careful however that it's mentioned to give wrong distribution as stated in one of the comments

Comment: @Pavan how can I understand result right or not?

Comment: What the result of the query? try running it.

Comment: Did my suggestion worked?

Comment: Please wait, I'll answer you few hours later

Answer (score 2):

According to Efraimidis & Spirakis's paper:
https://utopia.duth.gr/~pefraimi/research/data/2007EncOfAlg.pdf

If you are using postgres:

```
Product.order("RANDOM() ^ (1.0 / weight) DESC").limit(2)
```

proof of concept: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/474d2/4/0

As you can see the distribution is as expected