# C# SQL Random Sample using local database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, ms-access

I was wondering how can i get n number of samples randomly from a  local database using c#

What I have done so far.

```
"SELECT TOP "+n+" QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER FROM qPIPE WHERE CONTENT = 'Topic' ORDER BY RAND()"

"SELECT QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER FROM qPIPE WHERE CONTENT = 'Topic' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT "+n+""
```

error: Additional information: Undefined function 'RAND' in expression.

```
"SELECT TOP "+n+" QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER FROM qPIPE WHERE CONTENT = 'Topic' ORDER BY NEWID()"
```

Additional information: Undefined function 'NEWID' in expression.

My connection string

```
ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0DataSource=|DataDirectory|\questionbank.accdb";
```

But when I try to query it to MS SQL

```
SELECT TOP n QUESTION, C1, C2, C3, C4, ANSWER FROM qPIPE WHERE CONTENT = 'Topic' ORDER BY NEWID()
```

It works fine. Get n number of questions from the table with the matching topic.

Im using MVS 2015, MSSMS 2017. Working on a win form.

edit:

[using ORDER BY RND()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tuv3.jpg)

edit:

```
connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 2 QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER FROM qPIPE WHERE CONTENT = 'Thermodynamics' ORDER BY RND()";
            OleDbDataAdapter dAdap = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
            dAdap.Fill(dTable);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Why SQL Server when it states clearly that you connect to Access `questionbank.accdb`?

Comment: This might be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13040246/533120

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid concatenating SQL string (possible SQL injection). You could pass `n` as parameter:

```
DECLARE @n INT = 5;

SELECT TOP (n) QUESTION, C1, C2, C3, C4, ANSWER
FROM qPIPE
WHERE CONTENT = 'Topic'
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

**EDIT:**

Based on your connection string I assume that you are connecting to MS Access Database. Then you may use `ORDER BY RND(-(100000*ID)*Time())`. Based on [kobik's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19493100/5070879)

Comment: hi lad. i have converted string to int. my problem is usig the newid() or rand() condition.

Comment: @JepherJohnChang Try `ORDER BY RND()`

Comment: it disregards the n number of samples. but select all samples.

Comment: @JepherJohnChang Did you use `TOP` clause?

Comment: yes.
    "SELECT TOP "+n+" QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER FROM qPIPE WHERE CONTENT = 'Thermodynamics' ORDER BY RND()"

i have edited my post. you can see the picture of the query.

Comment: @JepherJohnChang Probably somethig wrong with your query (concatenation). Try: `SELECT TOP 2 QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER FROM qPIPE WHERE CONTENT = 'Thermodynamics' ORDER BY RND()`

Comment: still the same samples are shown.

what I have observed, yes It gives a random order but everytime i run the query it always give the same order.

Comment: still having the same result.

Comment: sadly. no changes.
"SELECT TOP 10 QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER FROM qPIPE WHERE CONTENT = 'Thermodynamics' ORDER BY RND(100000 * Time())";

Comment: i used ORDER BY RND(ID), it gives n samples. but still everytime i query it. same order.

Comment: @JepherJohnChang Did you add `-`?

Comment: ORDER BY RND(ID -100000*Time())?
like this? or
ORDER BY RND(ID ,-100000*Time())

if i use ORDER BY RND(-100000*Time()), same results from the picture.

Comment: @JepherJohnChang Like this `ORDER BY RND(-(100000*ID)*Time())`

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, you can use the `NEWID()` function:

```
SELECT TOP "+n+" QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER
FROM qPIPE
WHERE CONTENT = 'Topic'
ORDER BY NEWID();
```

In MS Access, you can use `RND()`:

```
SELECT TOP "+n+" QUESTION,C1,C2,C3,C4,ANSWER
FROM qPIPE
WHERE CONTENT = 'Topic'
ORDER BY RND();
```

Comment: hi gordon. i already tried that. but still having an error. but when i remove the ORDER BY NEWID(). i can select the first n samples. but i want to select n samples.

Comment: This answer works fine for me (SQL Server). Whats your error?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad OP connects to MS Access. And there is no `RAND/NEWID` function.